# using group by clause in subquery in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to use group by clause in subquery which is in from clause

```
select userID,count(id) 
from 
(
    (
        select id,max(bidAmount),userID 
        from Bids 
        group by id,bidAmount
    ) 
    group by userID
);
```

but this gives error

> Error: near "group": syntax error

Is it possible to use group by clause in subquery in from clause in sql?

Comment: I edited your question to make it more easy to read. You do not state what sql dialect you are using but you have an obvious syntax error in your parantheesis. You should also make use of aliases in subquerys as alot of sql servers enforces this for sub querys.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Check your (), they are not at right places. Should be something more like this:

```
select w.userID,count(w.id) 
from (select id,max(bidAmount),userID from Bids group by id, userID) w 
group by w.userID
```

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
select userID,count(id) 
from (

select id,max(bidAmount),userID from Bids group by id,userID

) as tmp

 group by userID
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `group by` in a subquery, but your syntax is off.

```
select userID,count(id)  
from  
(
        select id,max(bidAmount),userID  
        from Bids  
        group by id,userID
)
GROUP BY userid
```